# Install Lightscribe on 64 bit AMD Error

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, dpkg

I am trying to install `lightscribe` on a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed the 32 bit libs and I keep getting the following message:

```
tedsch47@Ted-Laptop:~/Downloads/Programs$ sudo dpkg --install --force architecture lightscribe-1.18.27.10-linux-2.6-intel.deb
(Reading database ... 574566 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace lightscribe:i386 1.18.27.10 (using lightscribe-1.18.27.10-linux-2.6-intel.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement lightscribe:i386 ...
Setting up lightscribe:i386 (1.18.27.10) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5': File exists
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens whe you run `sudo dpkg --install --force-architecture lightscribe*.deb`?

Comment: (Reading database ... 574566 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace lightscribe:i386 1.18.27.10 (using lightscribe-1.18.27.10-linux-2.6-intel.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement lightscribe:i386 ...
Preparing to replace lightscribeapplications:i386 1.18.15.1 (using lightscribeApplications-1.18.15.1-linux-2.6-intel.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement lightscribeapplications:i386 ...
Setting up lightscribe:i386 (1.18.27.10) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5': File exists

Comment: Please see my answer below. Hopefully it will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running these:

Take a backup of the file in question

`sudo cp /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5-BACKUP`

Remove the file

`sudo rm /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5`

Run the installer

`sudo dpkg --install --force architecture lightscribe-1.18.27.10-linux-2.6-intel.deb`

Refresh

`sudo ldconfig`